# Differentiation between Synchronous Domain Events, Asynchronous Domain Events and Integration Events

Tags: asynchronous, events, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs

While studying about Domain Events and Integration Events, I came accross articles that tend to refer to asynchronous Domain Events as Integration Events.

My understanding of Domain Events was that this type of events are use to notify systems inside the same Bounded Context of something that happened in that Bounded Context, and Integration Events were events meant for notifications that cross the Bounded Context boundary, so handlers for IntegrationEvents would probably exist in another Bounded Context's microservice.

I always thought that the differentiation was the scope of the notification, and not if it was synchronous or asynchronous in nature.

But I read some articles which refer to Integration Events just being Asynchronous Domain Events without giving any thought to whether it is a notification that's meant to go out of the boundary of a Bounded Context.

When an order is made, the customer would need to be notified through channels like Email. A Third-Party API will be used to do this. When an Order is placed, an OrderRaisedDomainEvent will be raised and a Domain Event Handler will pick up on this and send the email using a third-party. An error while sending the mail should not disrupt other things that to happen as well, so I'm assuming this should happen asynchronously. So wouldn't OrderRaisedDomainEvent just be an asynchronous Domain Event instead of being an IntegrationEvent as there's no messaging happening outside the bounded context?

So my question is, should I differentiate between types of Domain Events based on their synchronouscity(I think I made that word up, sorry :) ) and think of them as synchronous Domain Event and Asynchronous Domain Event and think of Integration Events as a separate concept, or should I just be thinking just in terms of Domain Event and Integration Event, when DomainEvents are just synchronous events, and Integration Events are asynchronously handled events?

Comment: Can you add a reference to the article you are referring to, please?

Comment: @SeanFarmar This is one of them. https://www.linkedin.com/advice/3/how-do-you-choose-between-synchronous#:~:text=Asynchronous%20domain%20events%20are%20those,service%20or%20a%20loyalty%20program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not wrong. Some of the domain events are handled asynchronously. But you make the domain more complex by handling every event asynchronously. So for some events, it's better to handle them synchronously because it would be easier to manage consistency.

An async or integration event is applied when you want to commit your changes independently from the event handlers. To do that, you can use an async event. But wait, why do you need that? If it's important to do sth in your bounded context after handling a command, why bother handling it asynchronously?

**Note**: *However, if you don't care about whether the event will be handled successfully or not, maybe an async event helps you to release the thread and be performant.*

To implement this separation of events, I would introduce integration event classes (the event arguments) in the application layer and let the domain event handlers or command handlers publish them. Domain models should only publish their domain events.

Going with this approach, it will be clear that domain events are the way to let outsiders know what happened in the domain. It's on the application's shoulders to publish the appropriate integration events.

**Note:** *Of course, you can do it on the domain layer, but I think it pollutes your domain layer with integration complexities.*

So to sum up, there are two types of events

- **Domain events**: events that will be handled in the same transaction of the causing command handler. (intra-bounded context). It says sth is acted on successfully but if other aggregates are not ok with it, the transaction won't commit. So actually the result of command handling hasn't persisted yet.
- **Integration (async) events**: events that will be handled in another transaction. They should be published by the application layer. They say sth happened and persisted successfully in my bounded context. If the others (other bounded contexts or the other aggregates in the same bounded context) don't agree, they should publish a compensation event to roll back the first action.

Comment: So you think of synchronous event as DomainEvents and asynchronous ones as IntegrationEvents? But then what about asynchronous Domain Events that don't cross the Bounded Context boundary?

Comment: Then in the case of notifying customers than an order has been placed, would the flow be OrderPlacedDomainEvent -> PublishOrderPlacedIntegrationDomainEventHandler -> OrderPlacedIntegrationEvent -> NotifyCustomerThroughEmailIntegrationEventHandler -> Third-party API to send notification email about order being placed?

Comment: @YaminNather As I said, it's easier to use synchronous events for the matter of consistency. Using an async event for a domain event in the same bounded context is not recommended unless you have a good reason.

Comment: the flow would be like this: "**publish OrderPlacedDomainEvent**" -> "handle in **OrderPlacedDomainEventHandler** "-> "if necessary **publish OrderPlacedIntegrationEvent**" -> "send message to message broker" -> "Async **OrderPlacedIntegrationEventHandler** calls Third-party API "

Comment: The same Microservice will be handling the IntegrationEvent right? Is there a reason we go through the message broker instead of just sending the email in a DomainEventHandler? Is it only for the asynchronousity, because it runs independently from the Command? Just trying to get a more clearer picture.

Comment: It might not be the same microservice. It depends on the design and situation. For resiliency, it's better to use message brokers. Using message brokers helps you to be fault-tolerant when the network is down, or 3rd party service is out of reach. In these scenarios, the messages won't get lost.